# Spot 6 - Reflectance calibration

Tags: remote-sensing, image, spot5

I have a Spot-6 image and the metadata contain 9 values of SUN_ELEVATION (BottomRight BottomCenter BottomLeft CenterRight Center CenterLeft TopRight TopCenter TopLeft). I've used before Landsat and this contained 1 value of SUN_ELEVATION for use in the flectance equation. Now I don't know how will use these values in the equation to calculate sin(SUN_ELEVATION). How I should combine these values?

**ANOTHER QUESTION IS ABOUT THE ESUN VALUES TO SPOT-6.. WHAT ARE THESE VALUES??.. WHERE ARE THERE??**

The header for the first question is:

```
        <Located_Geometric_Values>
        <LOCATION_TYPE>TopRight</LOCATION_TYPE>
        <COL>23169</COL>
        <ROW>1</ROW>
        <TIME>2014-04-17T15:13:27.828000Z</TIME>
        <SATELLITE_ALTITUDE>701584.630405</SATELLITE_ALTITUDE>
        <Acquisition_Angles>
          <AZIMUTH_ANGLE>20.5991408203</AZIMUTH_ANGLE>
          <VIEWING_ANGLE_ACROSS_TRACK>-1.90302747221</VIEWING_ANGLE_ACROSS_TRACK>
          <VIEWING_ANGLE_ALONG_TRACK>12.12965768</VIEWING_ANGLE_ALONG_TRACK>
          <VIEWING_ANGLE>12.3394936579</VIEWING_ANGLE>
          <INCIDENCE_ANGLE_ALONG_TRACK>-12.8322522348</INCIDENCE_ANGLE_ALONG_TRACK>
          <INCIDENCE_ANGLE_ACROSS_TRACK>5.13233998335</INCIDENCE_ANGLE_ACROSS_TRACK>
          <INCIDENCE_ANGLE>13.7633382493</INCIDENCE_ANGLE>
        </Acquisition_Angles>
        <Solar_Incidences>
          <SUN_AZIMUTH>62.3148341003</SUN_AZIMUTH>
          <SUN_ELEVATION>54.9137375042</SUN_ELEVATION>
        </Solar_Incidences>
        <Ground_Sample_Distance>
          <GSD_ACROSS_TRACK>2.14080821911</GSD_ACROSS_TRACK>
          <GSD_ALONG_TRACK>2.3337350258</GSD_ALONG_TRACK>
        </Ground_Sample_Distance>
      </Located_Geometric_Values>
      <Located_Geometric_Values>
        <LOCATION_TYPE>CenterLeft</LOCATION_TYPE>
        <COL>1</COL>
        <ROW>5418</ROW>
        <TIME>2014-04-17T15:13:28.832000Z</TIME>
        <SATELLITE_ALTITUDE>701597.12665</SATELLITE_ALTITUDE>
        <Acquisition_Angles>
          <AZIMUTH_ANGLE>30.6025825529</AZIMUTH_ANGLE>
          <VIEWING_ANGLE_ACROSS_TRACK>-4.51029940362</VIEWING_ANGLE_ACROSS_TRACK>
          <VIEWING_ANGLE_ALONG_TRACK>12.7678042112</VIEWING_ANGLE_ALONG_TRACK>
          <VIEWING_ANGLE>13.6401205795</VIEWING_ANGLE>
          <INCIDENCE_ANGLE_ALONG_TRACK>-12.9524184599</INCIDENCE_ANGLE_ALONG_TRACK>
          <INCIDENCE_ANGLE_ACROSS_TRACK>8.10746086821</INCIDENCE_ANGLE_ACROSS_TRACK>
          <INCIDENCE_ANGLE>15.2135360829</INCIDENCE_ANGLE>
        </Acquisition_Angles>
        <Solar_Incidences>
          <SUN_AZIMUTH>62.4597352167</SUN_AZIMUTH>
          <SUN_ELEVATION>54.6058551573</SUN_ELEVATION>
        </Solar_Incidences>
        <Ground_Sample_Distance>
          <GSD_ACROSS_TRACK>2.16790984064</GSD_ACROSS_TRACK>
          <GSD_ALONG_TRACK>2.33122811517</GSD_ALONG_TRACK>
        </Ground_Sample_Distance>
      </Located_Geometric_Values>
      <Located_Geometric_Values>
        <LOCATION_TYPE>Center</LOCATION_TYPE>
        <COL>11586</COL>
        <ROW>5418</ROW>
        <TIME>2014-04-17T15:13:28.889000Z</TIME>
        <SATELLITE_ALTITUDE>701597.834082</SATELLITE_ALTITUDE>
        <Acquisition_Angles>
          <AZIMUTH_ANGLE>25.2806645718</AZIMUTH_ANGLE>
          <VIEWING_ANGLE_ACROSS_TRACK>-3.13630286198</VIEWING_ANGLE_ACROSS_TRACK>
          <VIEWING_ANGLE_ALONG_TRACK>12.4550951922</VIEWING_ANGLE_ALONG_TRACK>
          <VIEWING_ANGLE>12.9859855447</VIEWING_ANGLE>
          <INCIDENCE_ANGLE_ALONG_TRACK>-12.9212204779</INCIDENCE_ANGLE_ALONG_TRACK>
          <INCIDENCE_ANGLE_ACROSS_TRACK>6.38122383831</INCIDENCE_ANGLE_ACROSS_TRACK>
          <INCIDENCE_ANGLE>14.4843704031</INCIDENCE_ANGLE>
        </Acquisition_Angles>
        <Solar_Incidences>
          <SUN_AZIMUTH>62.3396191484</SUN_AZIMUTH>
          <SUN_ELEVATION>54.7446239807</SUN_ELEVATION>
        </Solar_Incidences>
        <Ground_Sample_Distance>
          <GSD_ACROSS_TRACK>2.14574425486</GSD_ACROSS_TRACK>
          <GSD_ALONG_TRACK>2.34669128077</GSD_ALONG_TRACK>
        </Ground_Sample_Distance>
      </Located_Geometric_Values>
      <Located_Geometric_Values>
        <LOCATION_TYPE>CenterRight</LOCATION_TYPE>
        <COL>23169</COL>
        <ROW>5418</ROW>
        <TIME>2014-04-17T15:13:28.945000Z</TIME>
        <SATELLITE_ALTITUDE>701598.530095</SATELLITE_ALTITUDE>
        <Acquisition_Angles>
          <AZIMUTH_ANGLE>19.9565074408</AZIMUTH_ANGLE>
          <VIEWING_ANGLE_ACROSS_TRACK>-1.76271955049</VIEWING_ANGLE_ACROSS_TRACK>
          <VIEWING_ANGLE_ALONG_TRACK>12.1425169852</VIEWING_ANGLE_ALONG_TRACK>
          <VIEWING_ANGLE>12.3332746441</VIEWING_ANGLE>
          <INCIDENCE_ANGLE_ALONG_TRACK>-12.8909872182</INCIDENCE_ANGLE_ALONG_TRACK>
          <INCIDENCE_ANGLE_ACROSS_TRACK>4.6455241327</INCIDENCE_ANGLE_ACROSS_TRACK>
          <INCIDENCE_ANGLE>13.7567884142</INCIDENCE_ANGLE>
        </Acquisition_Angles>
        <Solar_Incidences>
          <SUN_AZIMUTH>62.2195675283</SUN_AZIMUTH>
          <SUN_ELEVATION>54.8833713072</SUN_ELEVATION>
        </Solar_Incidences>
        <Ground_Sample_Distance>
          <GSD_ACROSS_TRACK>2.12313579954</GSD_ACROSS_TRACK>
          <GSD_ALONG_TRACK>2.36323624406</GSD_ALONG_TRACK>
        </Ground_Sample_Distance>
      </Located_Geometric_Values>
      <Located_Geometric_Values>
        <LOCATION_TYPE>BottomLeft</LOCATION_TYPE>
        <COL>1</COL>
        <ROW>10833</ROW>
        <TIME>2014-04-17T15:13:29.951000Z</TIME>
        <SATELLITE_ALTITUDE>701611.055334</SATELLITE_ALTITUDE>
        <Acquisition_Angles>
          <AZIMUTH_ANGLE>30.0393683451</AZIMUTH_ANGLE>
          <VIEWING_ANGLE_ACROSS_TRACK>-4.37063958883</VIEWING_ANGLE_ACROSS_TRACK>
          <VIEWING_ANGLE_ALONG_TRACK>12.7794685841</VIEWING_ANGLE_ALONG_TRACK>
          <VIEWING_ANGLE>13.609226307</VIEWING_ANGLE>
          <INCIDENCE_ANGLE_ALONG_TRACK>-12.9915180426</INCIDENCE_ANGLE_ALONG_TRACK>
          <INCIDENCE_ANGLE_ACROSS_TRACK>7.82212237621</INCIDENCE_ANGLE_ACROSS_TRACK>
          <INCIDENCE_ANGLE>15.1795500477</INCIDENCE_ANGLE>
        </Acquisition_Angles>
        <Solar_Incidences>
          <SUN_AZIMUTH>62.3651154507</SUN_AZIMUTH>
          <SUN_ELEVATION>54.5756410132</SUN_ELEVATION>
        </Solar_Incidences>
        <Ground_Sample_Distance>
          <GSD_ACROSS_TRACK>2.1593044921</GSD_ACROSS_TRACK>
          <GSD_ALONG_TRACK>2.33896262245</GSD_ALONG_TRACK>
        </Ground_Sample_Distance>
      </Located_Geometric_Values>
      <Located_Geometric_Values>
        <LOCATION_TYPE>BottomCenter</LOCATION_TYPE>
        <COL>11586</COL>
        <ROW>10833</ROW>
        <TIME>2014-04-17T15:13:30.006000Z</TIME>
        <SATELLITE_ALTITUDE>701611.745696</SATELLITE_ALTITUDE>
        <Acquisition_Angles>
          <AZIMUTH_ANGLE>24.6777067024</AZIMUTH_ANGLE>
          <VIEWING_ANGLE_ACROSS_TRACK>-2.99633305079</VIEWING_ANGLE_ACROSS_TRACK>
          <VIEWING_ANGLE_ALONG_TRACK>12.4673539097</VIEWING_ANGLE_ALONG_TRACK>
          <VIEWING_ANGLE>12.9674591697</VIEWING_ANGLE>
          <INCIDENCE_ANGLE_ALONG_TRACK>-12.9701540154</INCIDENCE_ANGLE_ALONG_TRACK>
          <INCIDENCE_ANGLE_ACROSS_TRACK>5.99494281947</INCIDENCE_ANGLE_ACROSS_TRACK>
          <INCIDENCE_ANGLE>14.4641360419</INCIDENCE_ANGLE>
        </Acquisition_Angles>
        <Solar_Incidences>
          <SUN_AZIMUTH>62.2446915519</SUN_AZIMUTH>
          <SUN_ELEVATION>54.7143402244</SUN_ELEVATION>
        </Solar_Incidences>
        <Ground_Sample_Distance>
          <GSD_ACROSS_TRACK>2.13259585466</GSD_ACROSS_TRACK>
          <GSD_ALONG_TRACK>2.36533405587</GSD_ALONG_TRACK>
        </Ground_Sample_Distance>
      </Located_Geometric_Values>
      <Located_Geometric_Values>
        <LOCATION_TYPE>BottomRight</LOCATION_TYPE>
        <COL>23169</COL>
        <ROW>10833</ROW>
        <TIME>2014-04-17T15:13:30.061000Z</TIME>
        <SATELLITE_ALTITUDE>701612.424576</SATELLITE_ALTITUDE>
        <Acquisition_Angles>
          <AZIMUTH_ANGLE>19.3139141146</AZIMUTH_ANGLE>
          <VIEWING_ANGLE_ACROSS_TRACK>-1.62244118348</VIEWING_ANGLE_ACROSS_TRACK>
          <VIEWING_ANGLE_ALONG_TRACK>12.1553682721</VIEWING_ANGLE_ALONG_TRACK>
          <VIEWING_ANGLE>12.3270833097</VIEWING_ANGLE>
          <INCIDENCE_ANGLE_ALONG_TRACK>-12.9497282578</INCIDENCE_ANGLE_ALONG_TRACK>
          <INCIDENCE_ANGLE_ACROSS_TRACK>4.15857053102</INCIDENCE_ANGLE_ACROSS_TRACK>
          <INCIDENCE_ANGLE>13.7502691903</INCIDENCE_ANGLE>
        </Acquisition_Angles>
        <Solar_Incidences>
          <SUN_AZIMUTH>62.1243336098</SUN_AZIMUTH>
          <SUN_ELEVATION>54.8530184038</SUN_ELEVATION>
        </Solar_Incidences>
        <Ground_Sample_Distance>
          <GSD_ACROSS_TRACK>2.10545648282</GSD_ACROSS_TRACK>
          <GSD_ALONG_TRACK>2.39275823656</GSD_ALONG_TRACK>
        </Ground_Sample_Distance>
      </Located_Geometric_Values>
    </Use_Area>   </Geometric_Data>
```

Comment: This sounds like an error in the header. Could you post the section in question? The sun elevation and sun angle should be scene center and associated with a single value. The swath size is not large enough to even require separate values for sun elevation as the would be quite uniform. I would imagine that if for some reason these values are valid your could just average them to acquire a single coefficient.

Comment: ok.. I've edited the question and added the piece of header of "DIM_SPOT6_xxxxxx.XML"

Comment: Another question is about the ESUN values to SPOT-6.. what are these values?? where are there?

Comment: ESUN is the earth/sun distance and it is not a coefficient in the header. It is a standard distance based on Julian date. Here is a spreadsheet that has the values. http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Flandsathandbook.gsfc.nasa.gov%2Fexcel_docs%2Fd.xls&ei=2PIZVPnsMsmayATEkYDAAg&usg=AFQjCNGw60cnGaC46609cU3KkRdGpkUNtw&sig2=A0femSEE5CC6KrtRaQXsCQ&bvm=bv.75097201,d.aWw

Comment: I referred to: solar exoatmospheric spectral irradiances of Spot 6. I seen  that the reflectance equation is: rho=(PI*L*d*d)/(Eo*cos(SUN_ELEVATION)). Or maybe you know other equation for the SPOT-6??

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to directly apply the radiometric calibration equations from the Landsat handbook to SPOT. The equations are slightly different because the DN calibration method is different. [Take a look at the SPOT 5/6 handbook](https://web.archive.org/web/20140501211355/http://blackbridge.com/geomatics/upload/airbus/SPOT6-7%20User%20Guide.pdf) for the correct equations. You also want to use the solar zenith (not elevation) as the theta parameter.

[Here is a paper that extends the reflectance radiometric calibration to include atmospheric correction.](https://web.archive.org/web/20170809140059/http://www.mcs.csueastbay.edu/%7Egrewe/pubs/DistSensorNetworkBook2011/Atmosphere/Haxe_MultiSpectralData2_Filtering.pdf)